# How to create a build when I have not used npm to developed the project in angularjs (1.6)

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, gruntjs

I have user defined folder structure like this:

```
|--assets
|    |--css
|    |--js
|    |--fonts
|    |--pages
|    |--img
|
|--index.html
```

I want to create a very light weight, compact ( and minified if possible) build of the project, but did not used npm while development. So can you suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without gulp/grunt/webpack etc, you will have to do it manually using services like [JSCompress](https://jscompress.com/)

Otherwise, you can try something like [this post](https://codehangar.io/concatenate-and-minify-javascript-with-gulp/), using gulp.
It basically use the following gulp plugins

`npm install gulp-concat gulp-rename gulp-uglify --save-dev`

Comment: Thank you for sharing a solution. Unfortunately the code is throwing errors in angularjs ( I think the issue is because of the syntactical changes in the code which we are getting after we compress the script)

Comment: " Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?....angular.min.js "   -- somewhat like this

Comment: That’s a very common error and it’s most likely caused by a missing module or simply not in right order. You should be able to click into the link and debug check what’s the cause.

Comment: I do agree with the same, but at this instance that particular issue is only occurring when I do compress the code. So can surely tell it is the issue with the syntax which has got changed after compressing the code.

Comment: You can debug the code even it has been compressed. The source format button of Chrome developer tools might help.